# Please i want to get value of month and year from this javascript code as PHP variable $mm = ? && $ yy =?

Tags: javascript, php

Please i want to get value of month and year from this javascript code as PHP variable $mm = ?  && $ yy = ?
input name="startDate" id="startDate" class="date-picker"

```
<script>
                $(function () {
                    $('.date-picker').datepicker({
                        dateFormat: "mm/yy",
                        changeMonth: true,
                        changeYear: true,
                        showButtonPanel: true,
                        onClose: function (dateText, inst) {


                            function isDonePressed() {
                                return ($('#ui-datepicker-div').html().indexOf('ui-datepicker-close ui-state-default ui-priority-primary ui-corner-all ui-state-hover') > -1);
                            }

                            if (isDonePressed()) {
                                var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
                                var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
                                $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1)).trigger('change');

                                $('.date-picker').focusout(); //Added to remove focus from datepicker input box on selecting date
                            }
                        },
                        beforeShow: function (input, inst) {

                            inst.dpDiv.addClass('month_year_datepicker');

                            if ((datestr = $(this).val()).length > 0) {
                                year = datestr.substring(datestr.length - 4, datestr.length);
                                month = datestr.substring(0, 2);
                                $(this).datepicker('option', 'defaultDate', new Date(year, month - 1, 1));
                                $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month - 1, 1));
                                $(".ui-datepicker-calendar").hide();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                });

            </script>
```

Comment: [JavaScript runs on the client, PHP on the server](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/171203/what-are-the-differences-between-server-side-and-client-side-programming) - so you can't really do a dynamic date-picker with PHP nor can you propagate a PHP variable from JavaScript (without sending it to the server)... so what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: i am using this  html code <input name="startDate" id="startDate" class="date-picker" />
<?php if (isset($_POST['month'])) {$month= $_POST['mm']; echo $month; $year= $_POST['yy'];echo $year; }?>
<input type="button" name="submit" >

Comment: @AhsanNajam CD001 asked what you are trying to do, yet you reply with nothing about what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 4):

From the comment:

---

*"I am using this html code"*

```
<input name="startDate" id="startDate" class="date-picker" />
<?php if(isset($_POST['month'])) {
    $month= $_POST['mm']; echo $month;
    $year= $_POST['yy']; echo $year;
  } ?>
<input type="button" name="submit" />
```

---

Looking at your code you're not actually passing through variables called `mm` and `yy` (or `month` for that matter) - that's not what `datepicker.dateFormat` does - it merely formats the string going into your input field (e.g. `startDate`) - so you're explicitly excluding the day.

You can pass that date to the server and load it into a `DateTime` object.

You can use `DateTime::createFromFormat()` to do this **but** you need to add  *01* for the day when you create the object otherwise today's date will be used and that can lead to some unexpected results (e.g. the date being set to the 30th of February).

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['startDate'])) {
    $startDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/y', "01/{$_POST['startDate']}");

    // to output the month as 'mm'
    echo $startDate->format('m')

    // to output the year as 'yy'
    echo $startDate->format('y');
}
```

You never have to use the *day* value stored in the `DateTime` object but it does need to be there.

---

**Example**

If you wanted to put the *mm/yy* string back into your `<input ... />` field after form submission, say it failed validation but you want to keep the data the user entered in the input:

```
<?php
$startDateValue = !empty($_POST['startDate']) ?
    " value=\"" . (DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/y', "01/{$_POST['startDate']}")->format('m/y')) . "\"" :
    "";
?>
<input name="startDate" id="startDate"<?= $startDateValue; ?> class="date-picker" />
```

---

**References**

- [PHP DateTime class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)
- [PHP Date formats](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Comment: Sir i want only month and year.

Comment: @AhsanNajam - updated the answer. Technically both JavaScript's `Date` object and PHP's `DateTime` will hold information about the day but you can just opt not to use it for anything.