# How i can get value of month and year from this bootstrap datetime picker as PHP variable separately $mm = ? && $ yy =?

Tags: javascript, php

```js
$('.date-own').datepicker({
  minViewMode: 1,
  format: 'yyyy/mm/dd',
  autoclose: true
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.5.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.5.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

<body>
  <form>
    <input class="date-own form-control" style="width: 300px;" type="text">
    <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" />
  </form>
</body>
```

I want to use those variables there as a month and year for SQL.

```
$query = "SELECT  `distributor`.`distributor_name`, `orders`.*, `products`.*
FROM `products`
    LEFT JOIN `orders` ON `orders`.`pro_id` = `products`.`pro_ID`
    LEFT JOIN `distributor` ON `orders`.`d_id` = `distributor`.`d_ID`
WHERE MONTH(orders.order_date) = 10 AND YEAR(orders.order_date) = 2017";
```

Comment: didn't you post something similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46807151/please-i-want-to-get-value-of-month-and-year-from-this-javascript-code-as-php-va - even got an answer but that's still unaccepted/unsolved. So, was it solved? Notice the question mark here? It means something. Question asked, reply given. So, what say ye?

Comment: And what have you tried? The date and strtotime functions and the DateTime class are very handy.

Comment: You would need to `$_POST` the data to the sever (with either a form, or more likely, AJAX). Your `$query` is also vulnerable to SQL injection as it stands.

Comment: Not only was your question answered yesterday, but it was actually a *great* answer. I upvoted it, and you should accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll have to add a `name` attribute to your `<input>` for the datepicker:

```
<input class="date-own form-control" style="width: 300px;" type="text" name="date"/>
```

Next, have PHP accept the date, and convert it to a DateTime using [`createfromformat`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php), with the format you specified for the javascript datepicker (yyyy/mm/dd). You can then use DateTime's `format` method to output the month and year.

```
// Get the input into a date object
$input_date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y/m/j', $_POST['date']);

// Output the month
print $input_date->format('m');

// Output the year
print $input_date->format('Y')
```